# How to create a shapefile consisting of 2 lines using Python OGR?

Tags: python, ogr, polyline-creation

How would you create a shapefile consisting of 2 lines using Python OGR?

First line is no problem, but how do you reuse MyLine and Feature objects to create the second line?

Ultimately this will be in a loop with thousands of lines created...

```
from osgeo import ogr
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
datasource = driver.CreateDataSource('c:/temp/testlines.shp')
layer = datasource.CreateLayer('layerName',geom_type=ogr.wkbLineString)

#create first line 0,0 to 10,0:
myLine = ogr.Geometry(type=ogr.wkbLineString)
myLine.AddPoint_2D(0,0)
myLine.AddPoint_2D(10,0)
feature.SetGeometryDirectly(myLine)
layer.CreateFeature(feature)

#create next line 0,0 to 0,10?:
#how to you reuse the myLine, feature objects?
#myLine.DeletePoints()#something like this?
myLine.AddPoint_2D(0,0)
myLine.AddPoint_2D(0,10)
#feature.NesGeometry() #something lik this?
feature.SetGeometry(myLine)
layer.CreateFeature(feature)
```

Comment: Why not just create a new Geometry and Feature object with each iteration?

Comment: Yes different than arcpy where i typically reuse geometry objects which i assumed was faster than creating new geometry objects..my ignorance..new to OGR, experienced in arcpy

Answer (score 6):

You could make `myLine` into a factory function:

```
def myLine():
    return ogr.Geometry(type=ogr.wkbLineString)
```

and then for each line you need to create:

```
line = myLine()
line.AddPoint_2D(0,0)
line.AddPoint_2D(0,10)
feature.SetGeometryDirectly(line)
```

However this would be a minor gain. You could become more expressive and concise in this way:

```
def myLine(coords):
    line = ogr.Geometry(type=ogr.wkbLineString)
    for xy in coords:
        line.AddPoint_2D(xy[0],xy[1])
    return line
```

where `coords` is a list of tuples:

```
coords = [(0,0), (0,10)]
```

and it can even be longer than 2:

```
coords = [(0,0), (0,10), (10,0)]
```

and you would use it just like this:

```
line = myLine([(0,0), (0,10)])
feature.SetGeometryDirectly(line)
```

Incidentally, this follows quite closely the [GeoJSON specification](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) for LINESTRING geometries.

Comment: I'd possibly also make the shapefile creation part into a function too so you can re-use the code later.  The principle of DRY ("Don't Repeat Yourself") is a good one in coding.  I have a Python module that I have slowly built up of reusable bits of code like this and when I write some new code, I can simply import my module or functions from it.  If you are getting into scripting, then becoming familiar with the Eclipse IDE will also be a benefit in the long run.

Comment: Yes different than arcpy where i typically reuse geometry objects which i assumed was faster than creating new geometry objects..my ignorance..new to OGR, experienced in arcpy

Comment: To extend Sylvester's remarks---if you go with Eclipse IDE for Python work, I've found [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) to be a helpful plugin, extending the Eclipse dashboard with Python perspectives, as well as improved tooling (code completion, debug support, compile support, etc).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [ogr.Geometry documentation](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRGeometry.html#a1702b5b8142abe761061a6cd44e50b05) `myLine.Empty()` should do the trick.